# Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, application-error

I was trying to deploy my python project on heroku.
after successful deployment, when I am starting the app it gives me errors like...

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, **check your logs for details**. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

after clicking on above-highleted link I got these

```
heroku logs
2010-09-16T15:13:46.677020+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing PostController#list (for 208.39.138.12 at 2010-09-16 15:13:46) [GET]
2010-09-16T15:13:46.677023+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendering template within layouts/application
2010-09-16T15:13:46.677902+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendering post/list
2010-09-16T15:13:46.678990+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered includes/_header (0.1ms)
2010-09-16T15:13:46.698234+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed in 74ms (View: 31, DB: 40) | 200 OK [http://myapp.heroku.com/]
2010-09-16T15:13:46.723498+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts" host=myapp.herokuapp.com" fwd="204.204.204.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=975
2010-09-16T15:13:47.893472+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2 jobs processed at 16.6761 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

here's the log from heroku cli with error.

```
>heroku logs --app studimatess
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.2.
2021-12-12T09:31:53.735147+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=studimatess.herokuapp.com request_id=e0642f54-52c6-4bb1-acca-3ee63032b66a fwd="103.168.249.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-12T09:31:54.627463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=studimatess.herokuapp.com request_id=5c10fb52-090b-4ae8-9747-965b1a525105 fwd="103.168.249.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-12T11:02:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ashwinbehera980@gmail.com
2021-12-12T11:02:51.683639+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user ashwinbehera980@gmail.com
2021-12-12T11:02:51.683639+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 9b09151d by user ashwinbehera980@gmail.com
2021-12-12T11:03:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-12T11:03:18.001334+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=studimatess.herokuapp.com request_id=3e9f750e-3ff1-4800-8879-e52495e921b4 fwd="103.168.249.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-12T11:03:18.865139+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=studimatess.herokuapp.com request_id=52b06de8-2d56-498a-82e2-0236bb1b7547 fwd="103.168.249.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-12T11:06:46.690169+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=studimatess.herokuapp.com request_id=992ef88d-ffc2-483e-aa82-11d86b4787d0 fwd="103.168.249.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-12T11:06:47.483265+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=studimatess.herokuapp.com request_id=444243eb-84c9-4821-b029-2c916a580964 fwd="103.168.249.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

also, the proc file has code like this

```
web: gunicorn CCMS.wsgi --log-file -
```

how can resolve this error?

Comment: I guess you could try to change something in your code. It's hard to tell you any more than that, because we can only possibly look for problems in code that you actually show to us.

Comment: Also, the logs you show here appear to be for a _successful_ HTTP request, not a failed one. Please [edit] your question and replace these log messages with ones from a failed request.

Comment: I have updated it, please check. Thank you.